# Conda can't activate environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users>conda env list
# conda environments:
#
deepdream                    C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda32\env
s\deepdream
pd16.2                     C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda32\env
s\pd16.2
root                  *  C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda32


C:\Users>activate deepdream
No environment named "deepdream" exists in C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda32\envs

C:\Users>
```

I've made an environment for the deepdream code and I'm unable to activate this through the command prompt. Seems like conda recognizes it as an environment, but activating it fails

Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit the code into your question instead of linking/embedding a screenshot.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist It's the command prompt, not python code.

Comment: I can see that. I should not have used the word "code". Regardless, please copy and paste it into your question instead of linking/embedding a screenshot.

Comment: I was under the impression quoted code was necessary for ease of copy+paste for debugging.

Comment: Your question will remain around long after your problem is hopefully solved as a reference for future searchers, and we want to try to combat [link rot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300916/i-estimate-10-of-the-links-posted-here-are-dead-how-do-we-deal-with-them?cb=1). I asked because if that screenshot ever became unavailable, your question would be rendered meaningless.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I was trying to find something addressing this. Fixed in the question.

Comment: What version of anaconda is this? Can you post the output of ```conda list``` here or in a gist?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but the folder containing your environments is `env` but conda is looking for a folder called `envs` - you have two options:

1. Rename the env folder to envs
2. set the CONDA_ENVS_PATH environment variable to point to your path.

Comment: It's actually `envs` not `env`. See the bad line break in the pasted code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. My best guess is currently an old buggy activate script, but we'll see.

Answer (score 0):

I would recreate that environment. Sometimes, if something goes wrong during package installation, this can result in a broken environment configuration, e.g. missing/invalid files.

The activate script looks for a few subdirectories (and possibly more things) to decide if the given directory is a valid environment.

It is hard to diagnose your fault remotely, so I would suggest that you recreate that environment (simply rename the old folder).

If you want to diagnose the error, compare those two directories afterwards.