# Error activating conda environment

Tags: conda

I created a conda environment called py3.
When I try to activate the environment I get the error message saying `"No such file or directory."`

When I list the environments it shows the environment is in

`~/.conda/envs/py3`

I've read a few posts related to this:
[Conda can't activate environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885846/conda-cant-activate-environment?rq=1) and
[conda how do I activate environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35630276/conda-how-do-i-activate-environments)

Neither of the posts seem to have an answer for my issue.

Comment: How did you try to activate the environment? What OS are you on? What is the value of your PATH environment variable?

Comment: OS is Linux.  I tried `source activate py3`.  The PATH environment variable contains many values.  The first value is the anaconda bin directory (e.g. ./someOtherDirs/anaconda_2_3/bin).  I think there might be some administrative issues preventing me from creating conda environments, but I don't know how to check if that's the case or something else.

Comment: Can you please post the entirety of your PATH and the exact error message? It would help a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

Install a different version of Python

You can create and activate a new environment named snakes, and install the latest version of Python 3 as follows:

```
conda create --name py3 python=3
```

Linux, OS X:

> source activate py3

Windows:

> activate py3

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to set path for anaconda using:

**for anaconda 2 :**

```
export PATH=~/anaconda2/bin:$PATH
```

**for anaconda 3 :**

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

**for anaconda 4 :**

Use the Anaconda Prompt

and then

```
conda --version
```

to confirm that it worked.